# Avoid saving twice with ModelForm and m2m relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I have two models.

When `MyModelForm.save` function is called, I want to create an instance of `MyOtherModel` and add `MyModel` to it. To do that, I need to call `save` first in `MyModelForm.save` on `MyModel` instance, or it cannot be added to `MyOtherModel`.

The problem is `MyModel.save` is called twice because it is called again when returning the instance from `MyModelForm.save`.

How can I make this code work without calling save twice?

*ps. Many won't understand why I'm doing this, but I hid many details to have a minimal example.*

**admin.py**

```
def do_something(instance):
    foo = MyOtherModel.objects.create()
    foo.models.add(instance)


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.save()
        do_something(instance)
        return instance


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('calling save in instance')  # Called twice
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    models = models.ManyToManyField(MyModel)
```

Comment: @Sayse sorry this was an error, it was not supposed to be there,

Comment: Does the same apply for the `instance.save()`? is that there in your real code? that isn't needed either

Comment: @FelixD. I think, you can also remove `instance.save()` since the form's `save()` saves the instance already (unless you use `commit=False`)

Comment: I tried with `commit=True` but it throws an error `save_m2m` is not an attribute of the instance. `commit` is False by default in `ModelForm.save`.

Comment: commit is by default True. Make it false.

Comment: I swear it is False by default in that case, which is odd. When I print kwargs, it ouputs commit: False. Maybe because it has a m2m and because it changed in Django 1.9?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `instance.save()` call as suggested by @schwobaseggl ? Since `super().save()` (by the way you should have wrote `super(MyModelForm,self).save(*args,**kwargs)`) already calls the save method and you're calling it a second time after, your print statement is executed twice.